# Plotting of density estimates in matlab

Tags: estimation, matlab, pdf

Given the biometric match scores, I am required to plot the graphs of estimated densities of matching genuine and impostor scores. Following are the graphs I got for genuine and impostor scores respectively.

[image: PDF of genuine scores plotted against genuine scores]

[image: PDF of impostor scores plotted against impostor scores]

My question is how do i combine the 2 graphs and plot them against all the scores given in the data set in order to compare the 2 densities?
Can i do :

```
 plot(*data_set*,pdf_genuine)
    hold on;
    plot(*data_set*,pdf_impostor)
    hold off;
```

The dimensions of the entire data set are 517x516

Comment: Your intuition is correct. Experiment on it a bit and you'll get it. Having said that, I think the StackOverflow is the appropriate audience for this post and not CrossValidated.

Comment: You'll have a better chance that we can help if you post the code you used for generating those graphs; preferably a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please consider editing this code dump into your post. As you can see it's quite unreadable.

Comment: If *data_set* represents a grid of values over which to evaluate the two pdf sets, then your example will show them on the same plot. Can you clarify what "all the scores" represents and what the 517 and 516 numbers represent?